# string is not convertible to int (Swift)

Tags: xcode, string, swift, int

This is the code I have (my actual code is more complex, but I simplified it down, and I still get this error):

```
let x = "1" as Int
```

Xcode says:

```
'String' is not convertible to 'Int'
```

Am I missing something or is this a beta bug?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot simply cast with `as`. There is a method that produces `Int` explicitly.

```
let x = "1".toInt()
```

Notice that the result is of type `Int?` because Swift cannot know upfront if the conversion succeeds.

```
println(x!)
```

Or:

```
let x = "1".toInt()!
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps you thats how it should be

```
let x = "1".toInt()
```